# wcf-wcf byte[]/memorystream/base64string to improve performence

Tags: wcf

i have written wcf service(serviceB) cnsumed by another wcf service(ServiceA).

Both ServiceA and ServiceB runs same machine. i am using nettcpbinding. ( as it is good option for wcf-wcf commnucation also these two services are in intranet on same machine).

Operation Contract parameters for ServiceB are frontimage, backimage.

What is the best way to pass frontimage and backimage to improve performece. I am using byte[] ,

i..e,

here is operation ocntract for Serviceb

HashTable GetConvertedImage(byte[] frontImage,byte[] backImage);

my question is instead of using byte[] if i use memorystream or base64string will it improve performence. what about GZipStream?

i can pass required paramets while consuming it in ServiceA. Goal is to improve performence.

Apart from  byte[] / memorystream/ base64string  is there any other way to pass improve performence as will be dealing with large images.

please adivce

Also am using nettcpbinding is it good i this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your service to expose streams instead of byte arrays. Then you can set the transfer mode to Streaming.

Much more details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Comment: if i use streaming, it accepts only one parameter as stream right. in my case i want to apss 2 images. in that case i need to create 2 operation contracts and two ivocations i need to do right. plesae advice. is there any way we can pass two pramaters as  streams

Comment: I think the cost of calling two streamed operations is far lower that than the cost of serializing the binary data into one SOAP message. You can use custom header to pass additional information for the image (a id to pair the images afterwards for example)